# How to randomize 2 responses in 1 command

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Im trying to make a discord bot, and now Im looking for a way to randomize two or more responses on the same command, so if I say (for example) "apple", the bot can respond with "orange" or "pear"

I tried to do it this way, but the bot always responded with "Yes"

```
if(command === 'caracola'){
  message.channel.send("Si", "No")
}
```

Comment: Btw I know barely anything about coding, I just started learning

Comment: You're expected to do some research before posting a question. Googling "[How to pick a random item JavaScript](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+pick+a+random+item+JavaScript&oq=how+to+pick+a+random+item+JavaScript&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30l2j0i390i650l4.13293j0j4&client=ms-android-mpcs-us-revc&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)" is a good start

Comment: @Elitezen Thx! and yeah sorry, I did a bit of research by my own, but didnt find anything about this

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Math.random()` to generate a random number for the choices.

In your situation, there are two choices (Yes or No). You can imply `Math.random()` with the following method.

```js
Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
```

`Math.random()` gives random number between 0 and 1, while `Math.floor()` would automatically round off the number to nearest integer.

With this references, you can create an array for the possible choices (Yes, No)

```js
let ans = ["Yes", "No"];
if(command === 'caracola'){
  message.channel.send(ans[Math.floor(Math.random() * 2))]);
}

ans[0]; // returns "Yes";
ans[1]; // returns "No";
```

Numbers in `[]` after an `Array` represents the order of items within it. Where the order starts from `0`

### References

[Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) [Math.random()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random)